# Changing material of submesh on mouse click

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I create a cube mesh procedurally. Each face is a different submesh, because I want different materials on each submesh. The different faces also use unique vertices. When I click on a face, I would like to change the colour of that submesh to indicate that the face has been selected.

I am using the following code, but the submesh material is not changed even though it finds the submesh.

```
void SelectFace()
{
    if (!Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
    {
        return;
    }

    MeshCollider meshCollider = hit.collider as MeshCollider;
    if (meshCollider == null || meshCollider.sharedMesh == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("hit.triangleIndex = " + hit.triangleIndex);

    mf.mesh = meshCollider.sharedMesh;

    Mesh mesh = mf.mesh;

    Material[] materials = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials;

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.subMeshCount; i++)
    {
        int[] subMeshTris = mesh.GetTriangles(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < subMeshTris.Length; j++)
        {
            if (subMeshTris[j] == hit.triangleIndex)
            {
                Debug.Log("SUBMESH FOUND");
                materials[i] = selectedMaterial;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials = materials;
    mf.mesh = mesh;
}
```